# Is it possible to determine the transaction number of a MongoDB 4.x transaction?

Tags: mongodb, transactions

Is there a way to query the transaction number of the multi-document, multi-statement transaction being carried out in the current ClientSession?

Comment: Care to elaborate why you would want to find out the transaction number within a session ?

Comment: Would like to mark certain records (Documents) with the transaction number in which they were last updated in certain kinds of transactions, for a type of optimistic concurrency check.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on that with an example ? i.e. what conflict are you trying to detect, etc.

Comment: A network of objects is persisted as Documents. In long-running editing sessions, changes are made to subsets of the objects.  Consistent edits of groups of objects are saved in transactions labeled by the session.  All changes in the session can either be "deployed" or "abandoned" in another transaction; deployment applies them to the part of the store seen by end users.  Deployment will be aborted if any objects relevant to the edit (not just those edited) were changed by another session's deployment, testable if they are marked with the deployment transaction # in which they were written.

Comment: so you're trying to test whether conflicting transaction works ?

Comment: To determine whether deploying this session's changes would involve objects changed in another deployment transaction since they were read into this session, and whether deployment of this session's changes would step on the changes made in another deployment transaction.